# Mock Dependency Injection repository with filter

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

trying to mock repository :

```
 var expMock = new Mock<IEntityRepository>();
 expMock.Setup(s => s.GetMany(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>>()))
        .Returns<IQueryable<Entity>>(r => 
                               new List<Entity>{ new Entity() } }.AsQueryable());
```

but when i call it:

```
IEnumerable<Entity> source = _entityRepository.GetMany(w => w.IsActive);
```

i get an exception:

> System.ArgumentException : Object of type
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[Entity,System.Boolean]]'
>   cannot be converted to type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[Entity]'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply return value which you want your mocked method to return. In your case it will be *IQueryable*:

```
expMock.Setup(s => s.GetMany(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>>()))
       .Returns(new List<Entity>{ new Entity() }.AsQueryable());
```

Generic parameter of *Returns* method is a type of the argument of invoked method. `Returns<IQueryable<Entity>>` means that `GetMany` method should be invoked with parameter of type `IQueryable<Entity>` which is not true of course. That's why you get this exception.

Method argument is the expression, so correct mock setup should look like:

```
.Returns<Expression<Func<Entity, bool>>>(e => 
      new List<Entity> { new Entity() }.AsQueryable());
```

But thus you don't need method argument for providing returned result, use code above.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Returns()` statement is binding your `Func` to be returned when `GetMany()` is called, not evaluating the expression and returning the result. It should work if you take out the `r=>`. You can probably get away without the type parameter as well.